# Is it possible to have anchors in react-navigation as in html?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a react-native app where I use react-navigation and would like when I run the `navigation.navigate ()` function to assign it an anchor to let me go directly to the corresponding section as in html.

Is it possible to do this?
Otherwise would you offer me an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know with a [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) there's a prop called scrollToLocation. You can send a param through navigation for which section you want to scroll to and then that will get handled by the scrollToLocation. Not the same but it should work.